# Setting up a local development environment with nginx on Linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, nginx, chmod, chown

I recently moved to a new computer, and copied over all existing git repositories for webdevelopment projects from my old computer. On that old computer, I had installed apache to serve certain folders from as subdirectory of my home folder as development websites (either static or using PHP). So, for instance, a personal project would live under `/home/myusername/programming/personal/projectname/`.

Now on the new computer, I tried setting up nginx, to use it in a similar way.

I followed [this guide on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) to install nginx (and MySQL and PHP) on my laptop that runs Linux Mint 18.1 (Serena).

I configured nginx as follows:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

After this, testing by creating and `/var/www/html/info.php` (as shown in the guide) worked successfully.

I now tried adding a domain for one of my projects.

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/projectname.dev`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name projectname.dev;

        root /home/myusername/programming/personal/projectname/;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

(I also added a symbolic link from sites-enabled to this: `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/projectname.dev /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/projectname.dev`).

After restarting nginx (`sudo service nginx restart`), and adding `127.0.0.1 projectname.dev` to my `/etc/hosts`-file, I was greeted with a 404 error.

Looking in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I find out that the requests I do fail because of the following reason:

```
2017/04/17 21:38:11 [crit] 30176#30176: *3 stat() "/home/myusername/programming/personal/projectname/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: projectname.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "projectname.dev"
```

I expect this has to do with file/directory rights management in linux/unix. My home directory is obviously owned by *myusername*, while nginx is run by the user *www-data*. However, I am not sure how to alter the rights of this folder so that *www-data*/nginx is able to access it (and the files within).

How can this be resolved? And why did I not run into this problem while configuring Apache on my previous computer (also running Linux Mint)?

Answer (score 0):

I'ven ever used `nginx` but, following your hint - which seems correct to me - I would alter the permissions of the relevant files/folders by changing the group ownership to www-data and checking that files have at least 0644 and folders at lease 0755 permissions.

If you need your web application to write to some files or directories, either you change the owner of that files/directories to www-data or add the group writing permission (0664 for files and 0775 for folders).

Comment: But if they are owned by www-data, then I cannot edit them anymore as `myuser`, right?

Comment: With a standard set of permissions (usually 0644) no, you can't edit them as your user. To work around you can grant writing permission to group and add your user to that group. As you can see, the best approach is the one tailored to your specific situation (I approached a similar situation using `rsync` and a simple shell script, for example).